# Is wrestling like WWE Fake?

Tags: wwe

Is Wrestling such as WWE Faked as the moves that the Wrestlers do seem to be well rehearsed and they don't seem to get hurt

Comment: check out the film beyond the mat it's a good insight to what goes on backstage and behind the scenes yeah it's fake but it's still fun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [WWe's wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WWE), it is clear that this is just entertainment and there are no real fight:

> As in other professional wrestling promotions, **WWE shows are not
>   legitimate contests**, but purely entertainment-based, featuring
>   storyline-driven, scripted, and choreographed matches, though they
>   often include moves that can put performers at risk of injury if not
>   performed correctly.